# Safari WebDriver not registered on Selenium Grid 2

Tags: selenium, safari

I am able to run my script on MAC-Chrome and Fire Fox using selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar. But, when I run it for Safari on the same MAC, I get error:

```
**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, cleanSession=true, platform=MAC}
Command duration or timeout: 130 milliseconds**
```

When I registered the node I got following message:

```
MAC:/ labuser$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role webdriver -hub ://x.x.x.x:4444/grid/register -port 5566
23:08:11.804 INFO - Launching a selenium grid node
23:08:12.259 INFO - Java: Apple Inc. 20.65-b04-466.1
23:08:12.259 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64
23:08:12.267 INFO - v2.44.0, with Core v2.44.0. Built from revision 76d78cf
23:08:12.334 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match with current platform: MAC
23:08:12.457 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: ://x.x.x.x.1:5566/wd/hub
23:08:12.457 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
23:08:12.458 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
23:08:12.458 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
23:08:12.459 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
23:08:12.464 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@5097d026
23:08:12.464 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
23:08:12.466 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5566
23:08:12.466 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@12d56b37
23:08:12.527 INFO - using the json request : **{"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest","configuration":{"register":true,"port":5566,"host":"x.x.x.x","proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","maxSession":5,"role":"webdriver","hubHost":"x.x.x.x","registerCycle":5000,"hub":"...x.x.x.x:4444/grid/register","hubPort":4444,"url":"...x.x.x.x:5566","remoteHost":"...x.x.x.x:5566"},"capabilities":[{"platform":"MAC","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"firefox","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"MAC","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"chrome","maxInstances":5},{"seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","platform":"WINDOWS","browserName":"internet explorer","maxInstances":1}]}**
23:08:12.527 INFO - Starting auto register thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
23:08:12.527 INFO - Registering the node to hub :://x.x.x.x:4444/grid/register
```

---

Looking at the Json request at the node and the error in the script, I think that the safari webdriver extension is not able to register itself to the server. I am using Safari webdriver extension 2.38.0 (by The Selenium Project) and it is enabled.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get though it by starting the node as:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role webdriver -hub ...://x.x.x.x:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -browser "browserName=internet explorer ,maxInstances=5"

Now it runs fine